# Use of MPI_Type_struct and MPI_Bcast to communicate a data structure in C

Tags: c, struct, parallel-processing, mpi, memory-address

I have a data structure that I am building in series, i.e, on `rank = 0` using MPI:

```
typedef struct node {
  int nodeID,
  dof_u, dof_v, dof_theta ;
  double x, y ;
  char BC[8] ;
} node ;
```

I then fill in this structure for an array of 4 "nodes" in the following manner:

```
  int n_node = 4 ;
  int n_dof = 3*n_node ;
  node *nodes = malloc(sizeof(node) * n_node) ;

  if (rank == 0) {
    nodes[0].nodeID = 0 ;
    nodes[0].dof_u = 0 ; nodes[0].dof_v = 1 ; nodes[0].dof_theta = 2 ;
    nodes[0].x = 0. ; nodes[0].y = 0. ;

    nodes[1].nodeID = 1 ;
    nodes[1].dof_u = 3 ; nodes[1].dof_v = 4 ; nodes[1].dof_theta = 5 ;
    nodes[1].x = 0. ; nodes[1].y = 12. * 12. ;

    nodes[2].nodeID = 2 ;
    nodes[2].dof_u = 6 ; nodes[2].dof_v = 7 ; nodes[2].dof_theta = 8 ;
    nodes[2].x = 9. * 12. ; nodes[2].y = 12. * 12. ;

    nodes[3].nodeID = 3 ;
    nodes[3].dof_u = 9 ; nodes[3].dof_v = 10 ; nodes[3].dof_theta = 11 ;
    nodes[3].x = 9. * 12. ; nodes[3].y = 0. ;
```

This worked in in series, before I added any MPI stuff. Of course, my problem now that I am using MPI is that all of this information only lives on proc 0, but I want to communicate it to all procs using `MPI_Bcast`. First, I created an `MPI_Datatype` to be able to pass to `MPI_Bcast`. Then I used `MPI_Address` in order to determine the `MPI_Aint` array that I need to create an `MPI_Type_struct` for my `node` `struct`.

My current implementation is bugged, i.e., the data is not being communicated to all procs:

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n_node ; i++) {
      MPI_Datatype node ;
      MPI_Datatype type[7] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT,
                              MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_CHAR} ;
      int blocklen[7] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8} ;
      MPI_Aint disp[7] ;

      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].nodeID, &disp[0]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].dof_u, &disp[1]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].dof_v, &disp[2]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].dof_theta, &disp[3]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].x, &disp[4]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].y, &disp[5]) ;
      MPI_Address(&nodes[i].BC, &disp[6]) ;

      disp[6] = disp[6] - disp[0] ;
      disp[5] = disp[5] - disp[0] ;
      disp[4] = disp[4] - disp[0] ;
      disp[5] = disp[3] - disp[0] ;
      disp[2] = disp[2] - disp[0] ;
      disp[1] = disp[1] - disp[0] ;
      disp[0] = 0 ;

      MPI_Type_struct(7, blocklen, disp, type, &node) ;
      MPI_Type_commit(&node) ;

      MPI_Bcast(&nodes[i], 1, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) ;

      MPI_Type_free(&node) ;
    }
```

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong with what I have done here? Perhaps I am calculating the relative offsets incorrectly, or this can't be done in a `for` loop? I'm not sure. I have no prior experience with this.

Comment: at first glance that sounds correct. I'd rather use the `offsetof()` macro or the `MPI_Aint_diff()` function in order to populate the `disp` array, and that being said, this is unlikely the root cause of your problem. You will more likely receive some help if you edit your question with a [MCVE] (since the issue might be in the code you did not post)

Comment: as a matter of style and performance, you do not need the `for` loop at all since you can broadcast `n_node` elements at once (and that being said, you might have to `MPI_Type_create_resized()` the derived datatype to accomodate padding the compiler could have added). In any case, the `node` derived datatype (creation and destruction) can be moved outside of the `for` loop.